# Camel K doesnt download files from FTP

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp, apache-camel-k

I run the below Java Camel route to download new files from the FTP server, but doesn't seem to work. However, it doesn't show any errors too. The app starts with the status

```
Routes startup summary (total:1 started:1)
[2] 2021-07-22 07:03:45,885 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main)     Started route1 (ftp://user1@ftp.mycompany.com/customer-1)
```

The FTP route code

```
// camel-k: language=java

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class FTPDownloader extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("ftp://user1@ftp.mycompany.com/customer-1?password=RAW(Password)&delay=5s&delete=true")
        .to("file:///tmp/data").log("downloaded");
  }
}
```

Note: I have setup the Camel K in local Kind cluster.
`$ kamel run FTPDownloader.java --dev`

Comment: Path specified in route is treated as relative to home directory. Make sure, you have folder  `customer-1` in `user1`'s home directory. You can also try to view folder tree on FTP sever and find second folder named `customer-1`, because Camel automatically created one in the expected location..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to be the "passive" mode expected by the ftp server. The app started working once I have configured the `passiveMode` like below.

```
from("ftp://user1@ftp.mycompany.com/customer-1?password=RAW(Password)&delay=5s&delete=true&passiveMode=true")
        .to("file:///tmp/data").log("downloaded");
```